# aspnet Mvc Visual Studio 2012 aspx href

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, aspxgridview, location-href

I am working on an aspnet MVC 3 project under visual 2012. I hava an **Home/Index.aspx** file which is referencing a remote javascripts ressource and css ressource like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/css/theme.bootstrap.css"/>
```

This is working without problem.

Now in order to boot my application pages loading, a have made a copy of those files in a local folder (Home/tablesorter) but when I reference them again it's not working:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
```

I have tried this :

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="<%= Url.Content("tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.js") %>"></script>
```

but without success.

Could you please tell me what's wrong with my code.

Thank you in advance (I am newer in .net)

Comment: Why do you show 'good' sample for CSS, and 'bad' for JS? How this link is rendered in HTML? What browser shows for this link in console / F12 network?

Comment: Place your js file in the root web app folder like `approot\js\jquery.tablesorter.js` and use `<script type='text/javascript' src="/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>`. MVC has route engine which checks for files from root directory it does not look inside your `Home\tablesorter` folder.

Comment: Thank you, But It didn't work at all, I tried your solution, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Drag the JS or CSS file from folder and drop on aspx page it will automatically add the correct path.

Comment: Hello,You are right, it automatically add the correct path, but it seems, that's not the problem, because I have the same problem(the html rendering doesn't include css file nor javascript)

Comment: The problem might be with visual studio (virtual path for instance), but I don't know  in that case what exactly is causing the problem and how to solve it...

Comment: Can you see any error in console.Also try to load file in browser just to make sure if files are rendering like this.http://localhost/yourfolder/filename i.e http://localhost/tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.js if not found you can try with different paths to check which one is correct

Comment: Thank You Ahmad, it works welle, I just had to add the port number in the url like:  localhost:port_number/tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.js